# Servidor Windows Server 2012 no permite la salida de Emails usando Apache Server

Tags: apache, xampp, joomla3, windows-server-2012

Buenas Tardes Comunidad

Tengo un inconveniente que me ha estado martirizando la vida como administrador de este servidor, tenemos un Cloud Server en 1and1.com, el servidor es Windows Server 2012 (*lo tomamos en windows porque en un inicio se ibamos a usar Apache y el IIS juntos, pero al final no se hizo y nos quedamos con apache en Windos Server*)

El problema es que tenemos montado XAMPP Server V.3.2.2, aqui tenemos montado varios website hechos en joomla, sucede que ninguno de estos website puede hacer el envio de emails hacia el exterior. Cuando en Joomla se activa la cion de TEST EMAIL sale la notificacion en Verde que la prueba fue satisfactoria y que el email deberia estar en mi buzon de correo, yo chequeo y no hay ningun correo, esto pasa en todos los websites.

Datos para tomar en cuenta:

- El Firewall de windows esta desactivado
- En el administrador del servidor estan abiertos todos los puertos.
- Cuando configure el servidor funciono por un tiempo luego dejo de funcionar.
- Los website envian email cuando los pongo en otro hostign (no es error en los websites).
- No tengo antivirus instalado

Comment: Revisa los logs de tus servidores. Sin la información concreta solo tendrías especulaciones, algo que dificulta el funcionamiento del sitio. La idea es que, en la medida de lo posible, todas las preguntas incluyan un __[mcve]__.

Comment: @Michael Incluso es probable que se estén enviando, pero que se estén rechazando por algún filtro de spam

Comment: Sé que va a sonar a perogrullada pero, ¿tienes un servidor de correo instalado en tu Windows Server? ¿Y lo tienes activo? Por lo demás, como dice toledano, va a ser muy difícil saber nada sólo con esta descripción del problema

Comment: Hola chicos gracias por responder, no tebfo instalado un servidor dd correos, lo que pasa es que este es un Servidor Web, y cada sistema o website tiene que enviar emails de notificaciones, msgs del usuario, etc pero por alguna razon no lo esta haciendo. Gracias @toledano voy a revizar los logs

Comment: Hola a todos, al final no supe que era la que estaba pasando, pues los correos no salia, lo que hize fue que me migre a un servidor Linux Debian, y ahi todo funciona fenomenal.... un poco complicado de configurar pero nada que San Google no resuelva.... les agradezco mucjo su ayuda

Comment: @toledano esta es la solucion que normalmente serviria...